# File appears as modified but has no change

Tags: git, sublimetext2, editorconfig

If I open a random file on Sublime and just save it, without make any change, the file appears as modified on git.

Why this happens and how can I avoid this?

Comment: What is the output of `git diff`?

Comment: Something like this: "warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in assets/styles/common/_variables.scss.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory."

Comment: You have incompatible line endings in systems that are using your repository. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574435/git-when-used-with-mac-and-windows-simultaneously-gives-unnecessary-conflicts) for one example.

Answer (score 1):

Your editor has changed the Carriage Return (CR) or Line feed (LF) from one standard (e.g., Unix, Windows) to another. So the file has actually been changed, even if you can't see the change using a normal editor.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this? I'm using Windows OS and set this line on my git config file: autocrlf = true

Comment: Most text editors can be configured to not do automatic conversions. check yours.

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem editing my editor config file. Changing this line:

```
end_of_line = lf
```

by this:

```
end_of_line = crlf
```

And save all unchanged files again.

More info here: http://editorconfig.org/

Comment: How did you find out about it?
A simple *git diff* should have show you the difference!

Comment: @yorammi git diff show the error posted on comment above.